# Add Custom fields values to Woocommerce email notification

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, orders

I have added to custom fields on the checkout page using YITH checkout Manager billing_customfield1 and billing_customfield2.
I need to show this fields on the email sent by woocommerce.

this is the way , the fields from checkout are being displayed on the email template:

```
<?php if ( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) : ?>
                <br/><?php echo '<b>Nombre: </b>'.esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name().' '.$order->get_billing_last_name() ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>             


            <?php if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) : ?>
                <br/><?php echo '<b>Teléfono: </b>'.esc_html( $order->get_billing_phone() ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( $order->get_billing_company() ) : ?>
                <br/><?php echo '<b>Nombre de la empresa: </b>'.esc_html( $order->get_billing_company() ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( $order->get_billing_address_1() ) : ?>
                <br/><?php echo '<b>Dirección: </b>'.esc_html( $order->get_billing_address_1() ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( $order->get_billing_address_2() ) : ?>
                <br/><?php echo '<b>Dirección 2: </b>'.esc_html( $order->get_billing_address_2() ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ( $order->get_billing_city() ) : ?>
                <br/><?php echo '<b>Ciudad: </b>'.esc_html( $order->get_billing_city() ); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

I need to show the new 2 custom fields as well but there's no method for

```
$order->get_customfield1()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Woocommerce 3, there is a method inherited from `WC_Data` Class which is **get_meta()** and that has to be used on the `WC_Order` `$order` instance object.

> Most of the time, Order custom fields are registered in database with a **meta key** starting with an **underscore** in `wp_postmeta` table. 
>   So I will use: **`_billing_customfield1`** and **`_billing_customfield2`**

Here is your revisited code:

```
<?php 
if ( $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() ) {
    echo '<br/><b>'.__("Nombre", "woocommerce") . ': </b>' . esc_html( $order->get_formatted_billing_full_name() );
}             
if ( $order->get_billing_phone() ) {
    echo '<br/><b>'.__("Teléfono", "woocommerce") . ': </b>' . esc_html( $order->get_billing_phone() );
}
if ( $order->get_billing_company() ) {
    echo '<br/><b>'.__("Nombre de la empresa", "woocommerce") . ': </b>' . esc_html( $order->get_billing_company() );
}
if ( $order->get_billing_address_1() ) {
    echo '<br/><b>'.__("Dirección", "woocommerce") . ': </b>' . esc_html( $order->get_billing_address_1() ); 
}
if ( $order->get_billing_address_2() ) {
    echo '<br/><b>'.__("Dirección 2", "woocommerce") . ': </b>' . esc_html( $order->get_billing_address_2() );
}
if ( $order->get_billing_city() ) {
    echo '<br/><b>'.__("Ciudad", "woocommerce") . ': </b>' . esc_html( $order->get_billing_city() ); 
}
if ( $order->get_meta('_billing_customfield1') ) {
    echo '<br/><b>'.__("Campo personalizado 1", "woocommerce") . ': </b>' . esc_html( $order->get_meta('_billing_customfield1') ); 
}
if ( $order->get_meta('_billing_customfield2') ) {
    echo '<br/><b>'.__("Campo personalizado 2", "woocommerce") . ': </b>' . esc_html( $order->get_meta('_billing_customfield2') ); 
}
?>
```

It should works if those custom fields slugs  are `_billing_customfield1` and `_billing_customfield2`

You should need to verify in your database under `wp_postmeta` table that the correct `meta_key` are `_billing_customfield1` and `_billing_customfield2`…

If not you will replace them with the right ones.

---

You can also use the WordPress `get_post_meta()` function that needs the Order ID that you can have with `$order->get_id()` like:

```
if ( get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_billing_customfield1', true ) ) {
    echo '<br/><b>'.__("Campo personalizado 1", "woocommerce") . ': </b>' . esc_html( get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_billing_customfield1', true ) ); 
}
if ( get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_billing_customfield2', true ) ) {
    echo '<br/><b>'.__("Campo personalizado 2", "woocommerce") . ': </b>' . esc_html( get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_billing_customfield2', true ) ); 
}
```